# coffescript function - not a function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm having a problem with coffeescript, when I translate a javascript function to a coffeescript function via js2.coffee, i get an error in the console telling me it is not a function.  when i translate the coffeescript back to javascript, i find that it isn't a function but it's a variable.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my js function

```
function enterPasture (goat, xpos, ypos) {
  map.addChild(goat);
  goat.x = mapToPixelX(xpos, ypos);
  goat.y = mapToPixelY(xpos, ypos);    
};
```

and here's the coffeescript translation

```
enterPasture = (goat, xpos, ypos) ->
  map.addChild goat
  goat.x = mapToPixelX(xpos, ypos)
  goat.y = mapToPixelY(xpos, ypos)
  return
```

and here's the translation back to javascript

```
var enterPasture;

enterPasture = function(goat, xpos, ypos) {
  map.addChild(goat);
  goat.x = mapToPixelX(xpos, ypos);
  goat.y = mapToPixelY(xpos, ypos);
};
```

Comment: What does ‘it’ mean in ‘*an error in the console telling me it is not a function*’? Could you show us the exact message?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: enterPasture is not a function

Comment: @Jeff How exactly are you obtaining this error ? You're aware you can't directly execute CS in the browser ?

Comment: @Jeff Could you show us the code where the error occurs? I.e. where you *call* `enterPasture()`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no conversion error here.

```
function name(){...
```

is a shortcut declaring a variable and assigning a function as value of that variable. When written in the begining of a function or file, it **is** equivalent to

```
var name;
name = function(){...
```

In JavaScript, functions are ["first class citizens"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), which means they are valid values and can be assigned to variables.

Now, a problem arises if you try to *call* the function *before* that block. It works with the first notation, because the function declaration is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the start of the scope, but it doesn't work with the latter, as only the declaration (`var name;`), and not the assignation (`name = function(){...`), is hoisted. That might be the problem you had.

Comment: @aduch Yes, I'm trying to find a way to put that clearly (see my edit)

Comment: Agreed, it's not easy to phrase it clearly: "If there is a call to the function BEFORE its declaration, then it will only work with the form `function name()`"

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out, the function was getting called before it was defined, sorry everybody